# Как добавить класс '...' при нажатии на блок, не используя при этом "onclick" в html?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
<div class="to_expand">...</div>
```

Как добавить класс `hidden` при нажатии на блок, не используя при этом событие `onclick` в html, чтобы получилось :

```
<div class="to_expand hidden">...</div>
```

Comment: @ Alex Просто спрашивавшую, чтоб больше знать. А подскажите, если я напишу  <div class="to_expand  onclick="hidePlus()"> то спомощью какой функции я смогу добавить класс(и удалить класс)? Чтоб получилось <div class="to_expand hidden">

Comment: @Anastasiya  ну есть же документация [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/) и [на русском](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0) , в частности [работа с атрибутами](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%90%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8B) разве этого не достаточно?

Comment: Спасибо) Буду читать)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Либо в HTML onclick, либо все делать в JS. Но без указания этого event Вы этого не сделаете.

Comment: Я перечислил возможные варианты.

Comment: Я согласен с тем, что в любом случае идет вызов JS функции, но вариант реализации может быть разным: инлайново в HTML либо в отдельном JS-файле.

Comment: @chuhansergey Спасибо за более развернутый ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Добавлять класс по событию на щелчок мыши. Например mousedown или mouseup

Comment: Не думаю, что вопрос об этом.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: А как вы понимаете вопрос? Человек хочет щелкнуть по контейнеру и выполнить какое то действие, но не хочет использовать событие onclick. Ему прямая дорога в события javascript,я привел примеры

Comment: Так, как он сейчас отредактировал. Т. е. без использования подписки в html.

Answer (score 1):

Никак. Без событий javascript никак.